# Simple get from soundcloud playlist works well in postmann. But Fetch returns status 200 yet no response

Tags: reactjs, fetch, soundcloud

So I'm using the GET method with Fetch to get some data from soundcloud.
In postman, it works fine. But when i use Fetch I get Status:200 but:
'Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier'

```
const soundcloudUrl = 'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/473442966/tracks?client_id=IPz5SBL08EN3FyBabMnvLpb0AAKYGtrd&limit=2&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&app_version=1645088469&app_locale=en';
/**
 * @param  {string} url=''
 * @param  {string} method
 */
async function getData(url = '', method) {
  console.log(url);


  return fetch(url, {
    method, // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    // credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.text());
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data ? JSON.parse(data) : {};
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error); // reject(error);
      });
}

/**
 * @param  {object} data
 */
export async function getPodcaststreams(data) {
  const url = new URL('', soundcloudUrl);

  let response;
  try {
    response = await getData(url.href, 'GET');
  } catch (e) {
    return (e);
  }
  console.log(response);
}
```

Here's my Network response:
[network response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3iDe.png)

Here's the response I get in Postman:
[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAOCX.png)

Also, if I click the url, I can see the data.

Any ideas good people?

Best regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can see that you are doing wrong here. First is calling `response.text()` twice. The response can only be read once so

```
    console.log(response.text());
    return response.text();
```

will not be able to read `response` as it has been read already. This is why you are getting an undefined response when you try and parse the data.

Secondly, you don't need to call `JSON.parse(data)` as the fetch api includes a `response.json()` method which will parse the response as json. Your `getData` should look something like this:

```
async function getData(url = '', method) {
    return fetch(url, {
            method,
            mode: 'no-cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            body: JSON.stringify()
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error); // reject(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your edited version is pretty much how it was before I tried to console.log the hell out of it.

If I run your code I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input", but the Network still shows no response. If I change the code to ".then((response) => {
            return response.text();
        })" I get a blank response.
I have verified the JSON I get in Postman and there is nothing wrong with it.